# Python: Create new column that counts the days between current date and a lag date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to create a function that counts the days as an integer between a date and the date shifted back a number of periods (e.g. df['new_col'] =  (df['date'].shift(#periods)-df['date']). The date variable is datetime64[D].
As an example: df['report_date'].shift(39) = '2008-09-26' and df['report_date'] = '2008-08-18' and df['delta'] = 39.

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt
dates =pd.Series(np.tile(['2012-08-01','2012-08-15','2012-09-01','2012-08-15'],4)).astype('datetime64[D]')
dates2 =pd.Series(np.tile(['2012-08-01','2012-09-01','2012-10-01','2012-11-01'],4)).astype('datetime64[D]')
stocks = ['A','A','A','A','G','G','G','G','B','B','B','B','F','F','F','F']
stocks = pd.Series(stocks)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(stocks = stocks, dates = dates,report_date = dates2)).reset_index()
df.head()
print('df info:',df.info())
```

The code below is my latest attempt to create this variable, but the code produces incorrect results.

```
df['delta'] = df.groupby(['stocks','dates'])['report_date'].transform(lambda x: (x.shift(1).rsub(x).dt.days))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you update your post with the expected output please?

Comment: `df.groupby(['stocks'])['report_date'].transform(lambda x: (x.shift(1).rsub(x).dt.days))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution of using a for loop and zip function, to simply subtract each pair like so...

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
 
dates = ['2012-08-01', '2012-08-15', '2012-09-01', '2012-08-15']
dates2 = ['2012-08-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-10-01', '2012-11-01']
diff = []

for i, x in zip(dates, dates2):
    i = datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d')
    x = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
    diff.append(i - x)

df = {'--col1--': dates, '--col2--': dates2, '--difference--': diff}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
     --col1--    --col2-- --difference--
0  2012-08-01  2012-08-01         0 days
1  2012-08-15  2012-09-01       -17 days
2  2012-09-01  2012-10-01       -30 days
3  2012-08-15  2012-11-01       -78 days

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I hope that solves your problem.